# How can I obtain a Linux recovery image for a Windows 10 Dell XPS 13

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dell-xps

I recently purchased a Windows 10 based Dell XPS13 9360. It's a nice machine, but I live in Australia and Dell refuses to support Linux here. They do in the US and in Europe.

A standard USB flash drive install of Ubuntu fails. The live Ubuntu USB stick runs nicely, but it cannot see the SSD hard drive. That's a hard disk/motherboard driver problem, I believe.

- Will I be able to solve this problem by getting hold of the Dell Ubuntu recovery image?
- How can I get hold of the said image? (Dell Australia won't provide it because they don't support Linux, and Dell US won't because they know I'm in Australia).
- Is there any other reliable way of getting Linux running on this machine? (preferably a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu).

It was cheap, but I guess I shouldn't have bought the machine in the first place. I'm thinking of sending it back and getting my brother in the US to buy a Ubuntu version for me.

Comment: You may be overthinking this - there  is probably not a version of Ubuntu for it, rather some BIOS tweeks. I expect https://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04#868294 will provide the info you need ti boot Ubuntu. (Change from RAID to AHCI and a disable secure boot)

Comment: @davidgo Ubuntu supports secure boot flawlessly, no need to disable it. Other than that, +1.

Answer (score -1):

My thinkpad has the same problem, you should configure your bios into native mode and disable uefi mode. So it will be detected your harddisk when installation progress.